Type guards using a computed signal?
Is it possible to use a computed signal to type guard within the template? I am using Angular 17.0.0 (17.1.0 is required for input signals, which we can't change for this version of the library).
I have two tests within this component, one using a signal isItem, and one using a function isItemFn.

isItem doesn't seem to allow me to typeguard this.item.
isItemFn does allow me  to typeguard this.item.

Since the value of item can be one of three things (more to come later), I need a way to apply type guards in the template and I was hoping that signals would help but so far they have not. Is there a way to do this without using a function or a pipe?
@Component({})
export class CompositeChipsDisplayComponent<T> {
  @Input() item!: T;

  // Doesn't allow for type guards in the template
  isItem = computed(() => this.item instanceof CompositeChipsItemDirective);

  // Does allow for type guards in the template (but runs too often)
  isItemFn(item: unknown): item is CompositeChipsItemDirective {
    return item instanceof CompositeChipsItemDirective;
  }
}

<!-- Types work within the `if` statement when using a function -->
@if (isItemFn(item)) {
  <button class="item">
    {{ item.label }}
  </button>
}

<!-- Types do not work within the `if` statement when using a signal -->
@if (isItem()) {
  <button class="item">
    {{ item.label }}
  </button>
}

Here is what the output looks like in my editor:


this.item is not a signal. Why are you even using a computed signal? It will never be updated after initialization. If it was an input signal, it would make more sense.

I guess I never thought of that, any idea of a better approach? I don't have access to 17.1.x for input signals. Are pipes my only option here?

The problems with your code are follows.

You are using instanceof CompositeChipsItemDirective which converts the computed to a boolean signal, instead you should just return the signal after casting it to the directive type.

You are using a computed in the HTML, but you are again using the original input inside the template accessing the label. Instead using the @if as syntax and use the type coming from the computed signal, and it should work fine.



import { Component, computed, Directive, Input, Signal } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Directive({
  selector: '[someDirective]',
  standalone: true,
  exportAs: 'someDirective',
})
export class CompositeChipsItemDirective {
  label = 'test';
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    @if (isItemFn(item)) {
      <button class="item">
        {{ item.label }}
      </button>
    }

    @if (isItem(); as itemCasted) {
      <button class="item">
        {{ itemCasted.label }}
      </button>
    }
  `,
})
export class CompositeChipsDisplayComponent<T> {
  @Input() item!: T;

  // Doesn't allow for type guards in the template
  isItem: Signal<CompositeChipsItemDirective> = computed(
    () => return this.item instanceof CompositeChipsItemDirective ? this.item as CompositeChipsItemDirective : null;
  );

  // Does allow for type guards in the template (but runs too often)
  isItemFn(item: unknown): item is CompositeChipsItemDirective {
    return item instanceof CompositeChipsItemDirective;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CompositeChipsDisplayComponent, CompositeChipsItemDirective],
  template: `
    <app-child [item]="test"/>
    <div #test="someDirective" someDirective></div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

The @if is always going to return truthy, and since I have three different items, it is going to fail when the type isn't of that type. (CompositeChipsItemDirective, CompositeChipsDateDirective, CompositeChipsRangeDirective)

returning return this.item instanceof CompositeChipsItemDirective ? this.item : null; works though

@GetOffMyLawn sorry didn't understand that part of the requirement, updated my answer with the same, nice catch!
